# Provide instant filtering features for questions, answers, favs sections under one's account

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, autocomplete

It is currently quite hard or troublesome to try to find a question that I've aske or answered before, or even favorated, and *with certain keywords*.

If stackoverflow can provide **keyword filtering** features under one's user account, it would be nice, wouldn't it?

---

**Edit**

I don't mean a better way to the search box on the top right corner.

After I go to my account, there will be sections like `questions`, `answers` and `favorites`.

If you click into the section, then you see a list of posts related to you.

But they might be verbose or too many.

If stackoverflow provides a little **filtering** textbox under each section, I can just type  partial or complete keyword there, then the list will be updated immediately with what I am trying to find.

Will not this be awesome and more convenient?

---

Actually stackoverflow already has this feature, **but only for finding user** https://stackoverflow.com/users

Comment: Only few people will actually find  it useful, so it's a perfect candidate for a userscript.

Comment: Why is a search filter not enough? You can filter to your own posts, adding whatever keywords/tags you want, constrain by question or answer and more. Seems to me that if you are looking for keywords within your own posts, the search answers that need.

Comment: @Oded search is more heavy. In iphone or android's contact app, you can type one or two or more letter, the contact list will be filtered instantly. Don't you think that's convenient? Such kind of filtering box is utilised in many places, and very easy to be implemented. Even github implements this (the filter box above your repository list). It is definitely not to replace search function, but instead, compliment standard search by providing more lightweight conveniences.

Comment: @Oded Stackoverflow already provides the `my questions`, `my answers` sections (already a subset and already been virtually searched once), what one might want to do is to find out some particular things inside them, why one needs to type those syntax keywords again (to again get exactly `my questions` etc) and plus the filtering keywords?

Comment: @Oded of course, it would be fine without the filtering boxes, but as a mature product, all we want most are little features step by step, don't we?